# How to avoid running entire client-side process in Blazor WebAssembly before Azure AD authentication?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm building a Blazor WASM app with Azure AD, and I'm struggling with what appears to be an inefficiency in the way it's designed.  The entire application, including the home page, needs to be secured by `[Authorize]`.   It works (with one exception noted below), but the initial load is painfully slow.  Basically, on reaching the home page, Blazor loads the entire application -- running *Program.Main* in it's entirety, loading JS files from CDN or webpack bundles, loading all the .NET dlls, and ***THEN*** decides that it needs to redirect to Azure to authenticate.  Once it returns, it does all that again.  Loading the various files is not too much of a problem, since it gets them from the browser cache the second time.  The problem is that is also needs to run *Program.Main* again.

In my rather large client app, it takes a few seconds to configure all the services (I'm using a lot of gRPC).  The biggest culprit though is a call to the server API to get certain app settings that I don't want to expose to the client (basically doing [this](https://hutchcodes.net/2019/12/blazor-wasm-app-settings/)).  Moreover, that API call doesn't even succeed, since the API endpoint is secured, and the user hasn't authenticated yet, but I don't know how to get the user info from within *Program.Main*.  The log messages show that the user identity is not even created until sometime after *Program.Main* completes.  (One of the settings is the roles-to-permissions mapping, so I can't even draw the app's menu without it.  I've resorted to removing the auth requirement from the API controller for now, obviously not a permanent fix)

To replicate the behavior, just create a brand new Blazor WebAssembly app, selecting Auth Type = *Microsoft identity platform*, and checking the *ASP.NET Core hosted* box.  Then just edit both *appsettings.json* files to provide your Azure login info; change the requested scope in *Client.Program.Main* (and change the one in *WeatherForecastController* to match); and add `[Authorize]` to the *_imports.razor* file, and `[AllowAnonymous]` to *Authentication.razor*.  Finally add some logging `Console.WriteLine("Running in Client.Program.Main");` near the end of that method.

[image]

In the basic Blazor app template as described above, this all runs pretty fast.  Once there's a significant amount of startup code in Program.Main, though, it becomes quite noticeable, it can be several seconds both before and after the login redirect.  And I can't make an authenticated API call.

Specifying `endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html").RequireAuthorization();` in the server side *Startup* doesn't seem to make any difference.  Neither does adding `options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();` to the AddAuthorization call.

So basically, I'm looking to:

1. Identify the user in Client.Program.Main, so I can make a secure call to the settings API
2. Identify the user in Client.Program.Main, so I can bypass all the time-consuming stuff myself on the first pass
3. Get Blazor (server?) to somehow recognize that a request for a protected page will fail for an unauthenticated user, and go directly to the Azure login page without all the usual ceremony

Any suggestions?